# Linhas em Colunas

Tags: mysql

Tenho o seguinte resultado de uma *query*:

```
NOMECARACTERISTICA      NOMEINFORMACAO
Marca                   Samsung
Marca                   ASUS
Modelo                  E32 370E4K-KW3
Modelo                  X555LF
```

Minha ideia é transformar na seguinte forma:

```
Marca       Modelo
Samsung     E32 370E4K-KW3    
ASUS        X555LF
```

Eu criei a *query* abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NomeCaracteristica = 'Marca'  THEN NomeInformacao END AS Marca,
    CASE WHEN NomeCaracteristica = 'Modelo' THEN NomeInformacao END AS Modelo
FROM
(
    SELECT
       CAR.NomeCaracteristica AS NomeCaracteristica,
       INF.NomeInformacao AS NomeInformacao
    FROM
       caracteristica CAR INNER JOIN informacao INF ON CAR.IdCaracteristica = INF.IdCaracteristica 
    WHERE
       CAR.IdCategoria = 1 
    ORDER BY
       CAR.IdCaracteristica limit 4
) d
```

Mas está me trazendo o resultado:

```
MARCA       Modelo
Samsung     NULL    
ASUS        NULL
NULL        E32 370E4K-KW3 
NULL        X555LF
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar a obter o resultado que eu preciso?

Comment: Qual campo vincula a marca ao modelo? Tem alguma coluna faltando na sua pergunta (pra sabermos se o Samsung é o X555LF ou o E32 precisa de algum campo igual nos 2 casos)

Comment: O problema é realmente aquele que parece não ter nenhuma tabela de associação entre marca e modelo. Você deve então criar uma tabela que associa essas duas tabelas. Aí você pode fazer um INNER JOIN.

Comment: talvez isso ajude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns

Comment: Se não houver tabela de associação com PK e FK ai é dificil, do contrário, é possível fazer criando uma view.

Comment: Tente usar o MAX antes do CASE com GROUP BY.

Comment: Foi o MAX mesmo que usei.
Já funcionou!

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

desculpe a demora no feedback desse problema.

Conforme já havia sido dito pelo Bacco primeiramente, faltava uma coluna em uma das tabela para obter esse vínculo.

Dessa forma, consegui fazer a consulta que eu precisava!

Obrigado a todos!